# Android Wear Coordinate System

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

I am developing app which uses watch accelerometer, my questions are:

1. Is Accelerometer coordinate system on wearable devices same as in mobile devices like described here?
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords
2. May it differ from one watch brand to another?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if all the things that you will find in the sensors docu is applicable in the wearable device. Try to check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html), it is stated here that some wearable devices include a GPS sensor that can retrieve location data without another tethered device. So meaning not all brands of wearable device have the same capabilities. Just check the documentation to know more about Location awareness on wearable devices and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150631) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I asked about Accelerometer sensor not a GPS.

Comment: @ArtyomOkun did you find an answer for this?